# Set the same callback closure at two different places in code

Tags: ios, swift

Im wondering how from the side of performance and reference counting setting the same callback at two different places in code would affect the app? Can memory leak happen or something similar?

Lets take a look at this example:

**viewController** has a **tableView** which is set from **tableViewModel**

**tableViewModel** is connected with **cell** through **cellViewModel**

in **cellViewModel** we define callback:

```
var titleCallback: ((String) -> Void)?

var title: String {

   didSet{
    titleCallback?(title)
  }
}
```

in **cell** we set titleCallback:

```
func configCell(_ cellViewModel: CellViewModel) {

  cellViewModel.titleCallback = { [weak self] title in
     titleLabel.text = title
  }
}
```

My question: Is it ok to set the same callback in **tableViewModel** so we can pass title up to **viewController**?

in **tableViewModel** we set it like this:

```
var sendTitleToViewControllerCallback: ((String) -> Void)?

cellViewModel.titleCallback = { [weak self] title in
  sendTitleToViewControllerCallback?(title)
}
```

The same callback is set and triggered at two different places in code. What is the expected behavior for this and are there any drawbacks with this approach?

Comment: A closure can only hold one action. If you set `cellViewModel.titleCallback = ...` it will just override the previous one (just like a var). This mean only the last callback you set will be triggered.

Comment: @rraphael Thank you so much for your answer! I wasn't sure if that would happen, thanks again for confirming!